# MongoDb query in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have the following code:

```
if (user.getNationalities() != null && !user.getNationalities().isEmpty()) {
            query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("filters.nationalities").in(user.getNationalities())
                    .orOperator(Criteria.where("filters.nationalities").exists(false)));
        } else {
            query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("filters.nationalities").exists(false));
        }
```

The problem is, when I add subquery where nationalities are in user.getNationalities() or are otherwise empty, I got 0 results. When I do them separately, they work properly. How can I make them work together? It cannot be done in another way. How can I make this work?

```
public class Filters {

    private Integer minAge;

    private Integer maxAge;

    private List<Nationality> nationalities;

    private List<ReligionFilter> religions;

    private Boolean hijab;

    private MartialStatus martialStatus;
```

Nationality is an enum

Comment: can you post your collection also?

Comment: It is a collection of enums

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: Have you tried something like `new Criteria().orOperator(
 Criteria.where("filters.nationalities").in(user.getNationalities()),
 Criteria.where("filters.nationalities").exists(false)
)`